# How can I delete an object from getter if PersistedState is used

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I am creating a small website and faced with such a problem. On the site, I use PersistedState to save the products that I added to favorites. But the problem is that I can't delete this product since splice doesn't work. He only visually removes it, but it can be seen from VueJS DevTools that it is still there.

**store.js**

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from "axios"
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";
export default createStore({
  state: {
    products: [],
    favourites: []
  },
  getters: {
    PRODUCTS(state){
      return state.products
    },
    PRODUCT_BY_ID(state){
      return ProductId => {
        return state.products.find(Product => Product.id === ProductId)
      }
    },
    FAVOURITES(state){
      return state.favourites
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_PRODUCTS_TO_STATE: (state, products) =>{
      state.products = products
    }, 
    SET_TO_FAVOURITES: ( state, favouritesItem) =>{
      if (state.favourites.length){
        let ProductExist = false
        state.favourites.map(function(item){
          if (item.id === favouritesItem.id){
            ProductExist = true
          }
        })
        if (!ProductExist){
          state.favourites.push(favouritesItem)
        } 
      } else{
        state.favourites.push(favouritesItem)
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async GET_PRODCUTS_FROM_DB({commit}){
      try {
        const products = await axios("http://localhost:3000/products", {
          method: "GET"
        })
        commit("SET_PRODUCTS_TO_STATE", products.data)
        return products.data
      } catch (error) {
        return error
      }
    },
    ADD_TO_FAVOURITES({commit}, favouritesItem){
      commit('SET_TO_FAVOURITES', favouritesItem)
    }
      
  },
  modules: {
  },
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState()
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

**products-item.js**

```js
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
    name: "ProductsCart",
    data(){
        return {
            IsProductExist: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'FAVOURITES'
        ]),
        
    },
    props: {
        Productsitem: {
            type: Object,
            default() {
                return {}
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addToCarts(){
            if(this.$route.name === 'Favourites'){
                this.FAVOURITES.splice(this.FAVOURITES.indexOf(this.Productsitem), 1)
            } else {
                this.$emit('addToCarts', this.Productsitem)
                this.IsProductExist = true
            }
            
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            if(this.FAVOURITES.length > 0){
                for(let i = 0; i < this.FAVOURITES.length; i++){
                    if(this.FAVOURITES[i].id === this.Productsitem.id){
                        this.IsProductExist = true
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: you have a "ADD_TO_FAVOURITES" action, why not make a "REMOVE_FROM_FAVOURITES" action that you call after you splice?  therefore you update both the page visually and the vuex store

Comment: I can't do this since I can't in store.js  mutations correctly refer to getter. In the errors it was written that the state is not found.

Comment: It is also important to know that the state is empty after the page refresh, and all the data is in the getter. Therefore, it will not be possible to refer to state in the mutation

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. In mutation, as @yoduh said above, it was necessary to correctly refer to getter in mutations. Now the mutation looks like this:

```js
DELTE_PRODUCTS(state, {data, getters}){
      getters.FAVOURITES.splice(0,1)
      //console.log(data);
      //console.log(state);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```